# Mapping a throwing function in swift---double try

Tags: swift, error-handling, higher-order-functions

A very small question.  When I try to map a throwing function in Swift, the compiler makes me use the try keyword twice.  For a toy example:

```
public func combineFiles(files: [String]) throws -> String {
    let strings = try files.map { try String(contentsOfFile: $0) }
    return strings.joined(separator: "\n\n")
}
```

Both of the try keywords in the second line seem to be necessary in order to get this to compile.  But this just feels super-wrong to me---is there a way to do this kind of operation without a second try statement?

Comment: `contentsOfFile` can throw. Therefore it needs a try. You are not catching the try. Therefore it percolates up. So now `map` can throw. Therefore it needs a try. Otherwise what would happen if one `contentsOfFile` were to fail?

Comment: If you look at the declaration of map you will see that this is written in: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map The function it takes can coherently throw exactly because map rethrows.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you could have a single `try` if you avoid calling `map`:

```
func combineFiles(files: [String]) throws -> String {
    var results: [String] = []
    for file in files {
        results.append(try String(contentsOfFile: file))
    }
    return results.joined(separator: "\n\n")
}
```

But I think that’s going the wrong direction. I’d just embrace the two `try` pattern that rethrowing functions like `map` entail.

I’d lose `strings`, though:

```
func combineFiles(files: [String]) throws -> String {
    try files.map { try String(contentsOfFile: $0) }
        .joined(separator: "\n\n")
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I just need to recalibrate my sense for code smells :-)